# marklogic create instance error out on array - javascript

Tags: javascript, entity, marklogic

```
[javascript] XDMP-CAST: (err:FORG0001) xs:string#1(.) -- Invalid cast: `json:object(<json:object xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" `
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>) cast as xs:string
Stack Trace
In /MarkLogic/entity-services/entity-services.xqy on line 313
In xs:string#1(.)
fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/entity-services","source-nodes") = 
fn:doc("/budget/Accomplishments/objective/2019-6.json")/array-node("tasks")/object-node()
fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/entity-services","fn") = xs:string#1`

declareUpdate();
const es = require('/MarkLogic/entity-services/entity-services.xqy');
const Completed = require('/es-gs/CompletedObjectiveEntity-1.0.0-conv.xqy');
for (const source of fn.collection('Objective,Accomplishments')) {
let instance = Completed['extract-instance-CompletedObjectives'](source);
let uri = '/es-gs/env/'+ instance.id + '.json';
xdmp.documentInsert(
uri, Completed.instanceToEnvelope(instance, "json"),
{collections: ['CompletedObjective-envelopes']}
);}
```

I am trying to create instance documents but I error out on line

```
let $tasks  := es:extract-array($source-node/tasks, xs:string#1)
```

I am not sure why this errors out

Sample

```
{

"goal": "- Launched", 
 "tasks": [
 {
 "Task-1": "-- Step 1"
 }, 
 {
 "Task-2": "-- Step 22"
 }, 
 {
 "Task-3": "-- Step 33"
 }
 ], 
 "id": "1"
 }
```

Here is more code about the task

I have tire server alternatives to the code below. It builds and deplys the instance but there are no tasks in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MarkLogic will walk and work your tree like:

```
/array-node()/object-node()/array-node()/text()[#], …
```

Below customised module converts the array into canonical model using `MarkLogic Entity Services`:

> Within the instance data extract function, please ***replace*** your code

```
let $tasks  := es:extract-array($source-node/tasks, xs:string#1)
```

> ***with my codes*** (works for `0..1`, `1..1`, `1..*`)

```
==================================================================
    let $Tasks :=   $source-node/tasks[1 to fn:last()]
==================================================================
        =>es:optional('Tasks', array-node{$Tasks})
};
```

> harmonised and enveloped document

```
{
  "envelope": {
    "instance": {
     "info": {
       "title": "CompletedObjective", 
       "version": "1.0"
     }, 
     "CompletedObjective": {
       "objectiveID": "1", 
       "objectiveGoal": "- Launched", 
       "Tasks": [
         {
          "Task-1": "-- Step 1"
         }, 
         {
          "Task-2": "-- Step 22"
         }, 
         {
          "Task-3": "-- Step 33"
         }
       ]
     }
   }, 
   "attachments": [
     {
      "goal": "- Launched", 
      "tasks": 
      [
=======================
```

> NOTE: You can also leverage MarkLogic Data Hub Framework to facilitate data modelling.